# Raise error and don't execute else block if is the condition is true

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write sql script to update my table if some columns don't have null value, if it have null value the update statements will not be executed, my code here raise the error and execute the else block, why?

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from Trendline.Invoices where Trx_Date is null or Trx_no is null or OperaKey is null) 
     RAISERROR('This script can not been executed because of null value/values in this columns.',0,1)
ELSE

BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE Trendline.Invoices
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Invoices_RecSkpUser
GO
ALTER TABLE Trendline.Invoices
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Invoices_RecConfSkpUsr
GO
ALTER TABLE Trendline.Invoices
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Invoices_FollowUpSkpUsr
GO
ALTER TABLE TaeppaCore.Users SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE Trendline.Invoices
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Invoices_Currencies
```

Comment: Can you show some of the `ELSE` block?

Comment: What do you get when you execute select 1 from Invoices where Trx_Date is null or Trx_no is null or OperaKey is null

Comment: I get the columns which has null values, when I execute the if statement without else block, it works well, but when  I add the else block the script execute the if and else block

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function or plsql block for your requirement.

```
Declare
procedurename p(sales NUMBER)
BEGIN
IF sales>100 THEN
UPDATE STOCK set SALES=sales-100;
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SOME COMMENT');
END IF
END p;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ELSE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) will control the execution of the *next* statement, unless what follows is surrounded by a [`BEGIN`/`END`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx) block. So:

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from Trendline.Invoices where Trx_Date is null or Trx_no is null or OperaKey is null)
     --The next line executes if the IF was taken
     RAISERROR('This script can not been executed because of null value/values in this columns.',0,1)
ELSE

--The next line executes if the ELSE was taken
BEGIN TRANSACTION
--The next line executes whether either branch was taken
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

So the usual recommendation would be to surround everything that should be taken together by a `BEGIN`/`END` block, something like:

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from Trendline.Invoices where Trx_Date is null or Trx_no is null or OperaKey is null) 
     RAISERROR('This script can not been executed because of null value/values in this columns.',0,1)
ELSE
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  SET ARITHABORT ON
  SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
  SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  SET ANSI_PADDING ON
  SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
  COMMIT
END
```

But you can't have batch separators (`GO`s) inside of a `BEGIN`/`END` block - so you'll need to either retest your conditions inside each batch or find other ways to prevent the following statements from executing.